# Background cuts when scroll down

Tags: html, css

for some reason my background pattern get cut off when i scroll my page down (i set the body min-height to 100%)

[image]

I would like my pattern to fill the all height no matter how much content I have.

```
html,body {
  font-size: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../img/bg-pattern.png);
}


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "itc_avant_garde_std_bkregular", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
 }

#sparkly {
  background: url(../img/sparkly-pretty-pretty.png);
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: bottom center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

also the html

```
<body>
        <div class="row"  id="sparkly">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <div class="large-4 small-centered columns">
                    <img class="logo" src="img/common-code-logo-chat.png" alt="CommonCode Logo" />
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                        <div id="chatfield">
                        <img id"fade-out" src="" alt="" />
                            <p class="chatfield_text" id="text-opacity2"><span class="second_user" id="text-opacity1">Dan P.</span><br />Nam quis enim ut erat pharetra tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque vel urna sapien. Curabitur pulvinar mauris in nisl faucibus sed lobortis erat sodales. Sed accumsan sem eu est gravida mollis. In scelerisque, ligula id pulvinar congue, dui diam imperdiet risus, in molestie est tortor condimentum quam. Praesent elit enim, vulputate a varius sed, lacinia et mauris.</p>
                            <p class="chatfield_text" id="text-opacity4"><span class="guest_user" id="text-opacity3">Guest</span><br />_Thanks, although bla bla bla bla bla bla.</p>
                            <p class="chatfield_text" id="text-opacity6"><span class="first_user" id="text-opacity5">Daryl A.</span><br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse purus urna, lacinia sed malesuada eu, malesuada in sem. In ac eros quam, sit amet bibendum nisi. Nam in libero nibh. Nulla facilisi. Quisque eget arcu augue, tempor lobortis mi. Pellentesque bibendum turpis vitae dolor sollicitudin mattis. Phasellus libero justo, porttitor vitae fringilla id, condimentum vitae nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
                            <p class="chatfield_text"><span class="guest_user">Guest</span><br />_bla bla bla blabal bla bla bla bla?</p>       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="Talk to us" placeholder="Talk to Us">
                </form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">  
                        <p><span class="first_user"> Daryl A. </span><span class="second_user"> Dan P.</span> and <span class="more_user"> 4 more </span> are currently online </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

I am using Foundation framework..

hope it is not too confusing
thanks in advance to anyone who could help me

fabio

Comment: Provide a fiddle or link. As your CSS doesnt gives up the display that you have shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Of course things get cut of if you specify a height of 100% for html and body - the content that is higher than that will then be displayed outside of the element according to the default value of 'auto' for the overflow property.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sU2U3/

Comment: although getting rid of height 100% I get a white strip down the bottom is if the body was height wasn't high enough to fill the browser..

Comment: do you have live link for this? not jsfiddle...

Comment: it's not live but it's on git hub

Comment: @FabioVella : Check my answer.. it will work... & thanks for letting me know about Foundation framewrok... its looks cool...

Comment: https://github.com/fabiovella83/ChatApp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the background color from the html in normalize.css, it will solve your issue

```
html {
    /*background: #fff;*/ /* 1 */
    color: #000; /* 2 */
    font-family: sans-serif; /* 3 */
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 4 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 4 */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out `height: 100%;` and use as below

```
html,body {
  font-size: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../img/bg-pattern.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

`height: 100%;` is related to body height, so I think saying `height: 100%;` is useless. As background image was problem, you have to deal with background properties and last two lines will solve your problem.

---

### Edit 1

Use below.

```
html,
body {
  font-size: 100%;
  background: url(../img/bg-pattern.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  }
```

Comment: you can have  a look to the all project on github.com/fabiovella83/ChatApp